# Using non sub-multiplicative matrix norm for proving the convergence of the series of the exponential function of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

*Suppose $A \in M_{d \times d}(\mathbb{C})$. The issue of the convergence of the series of the exponential function of $A$ has been already addressed in this site. Some nice answers can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131013/matrix-exponential-convergence) which clearly explains how to use sub-multiplicative norm (more specifically operator norm) to show that $e^A \to  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{A^n}{n!}$. The striking feature of  the usage of sub-multiplicative norm is that it allows us to claim that $||A^n||\le ||A||^n$. Now it is not hard to prove the above convergence as the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$*

***But is there not any possibility to reach the same conclusion without using a sub-multiplicative norm?***

***What I attempted:-***  Let $A=\left[a_{ij}\right]_{d \times d}$. I would try to use ***Max norm*** which is defined as $||A||_{\max}=\max_{ij}|a_{ij}|$  in order to reach the conclusion. I will write $||A||$, in place of $||A||_{\max}$, to denote the max norm of $A$.
In one of my recent question, which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894312/if-cdot-denote-the-max-norm-of-a-matrix-a-is-it-always-true-that/2894500#2894500), I made an attempt to show that for any $A \in  M_{d \times d}(\mathbb{C})$ \begin{equation} ||A^n||\le d^{n-1}||A||^n \end{equation} Since $d$ is positive, it is legitimate to write \begin{equation}
||A^n||\le d^{n-1}||A||^n<d^n ||A||^n\dots \dots (1)
\end{equation}
Let \begin{equation} \begin{aligned} s_n &=||I||+||A||+\frac{||A^2||}{2!}+\frac{||A^3||}{3!}+\dots+\frac{||A^n||}{n!}\\
&=1+||A||+\frac{||A^2||}{2!}+\frac{||A^3||}{3!}+\dots+\frac{||A^n||}{n!}\\
&\le 1+d||A||+\frac{\left(d||A||\right)^2}{2!}+\frac{\left(d||A||\right)^3}{3!}+\dots+\frac{\left(d||A||\right)^n}{n!}\quad \left(\mbox{From $(1)$}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The right hand side of the above inequality tends to $e^{d||A||}$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, \begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n \le e^{d||A||} < \infty
\end{equation}

The immediate consequence of the above result is that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{A^n}{n!}$ converges.

Am I correct? I would highly appreciate any valuable guidance provided by the scholars of this mathematical community.

Answer (score 1):

Since $M_{d \times d}(\mathbb C)$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, any two norms on it are equivalent.  If $c \|\cdot\|_2 \le \|\cdot \|_1 \le C \|\cdot \|_2$ where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is submultiplicative, then $\| A^n \|_1 \le C \|A^n \|_2 \le C \|A\|_2^n$ and 
$$ \|\exp(A) \|_1 = \|\sum_{n=1}^\infty A^n/n! \|_1 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty C \|A\|_2^n/n! = C \exp(\|A\|_2)$$